# Conditional Formatting for filtered area

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, conditional-formatting, excel-indirect

I currently use the following formula in conditional formatting to highlight ever other row.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",MOD(ROW(),2)=0)
```

However I would like to find a way to modify this to only apply to currently visible section of a filtered dataset.

So for instance the above currently highlights every even row but if I filter the data set to only show rows: 2,5,7,9,10,12,15. I would want it to highlight only rows 5,9,12 or 2,7,10,15.

I am also wanting to avoid using macros I could write this into a macro but the end user of this file is unable to run macros due to their IT department not trusting macros of any sort.

I am using Excel 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try HOME > Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*, **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=ISODD(SUBTOTAL(3,INDIRECT("A$1:A"&ROW())))
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select formatting of choice, OK, OK.

Comment: This is close to what I want as this does take into account if it is filtered or not. However it appears to Highlight every row if the number of rows filter is even and does not highlight any if the number of rows is odd.

Comment: I am wanting every other row to be formatted by the conditional formatting and all the other rows to not have formatting. This needs to be dynamic for the filtering. The idea is the end result regardless of what you filter by the data will have alternating colors for the cells in each row going from the light blue the conditional formatting is adding to the plain white that excel starts with. This makes for easier reading of the data by the end user.

Comment: Let me test again then as that is not at all what it did for me

Comment: OK no idea what I did wrong the first time this works perfect when the data is filtered.

Comment: I added the if(isblank()) portion to your code as well so the formatting stops at the end of the data when no filtered.

Comment: Sorry let me re-explain. When the data is unfiltered the coloring was happening every other row all the way to the row excel has and not ending at the last row of data. The second you filtered the data that was corrected. So I added the If(isblank()) to the start of your formula similar to what I did with my first code and it stopped that from happening. All is good now thank you so much for your help.